# Cómo validar una fecha que no sea menor a la fecha actual

Tags: javascript, php, date

Estoy trabajando en un formulario en php para realizar citas, y tengo un campo para capturar la fecha de la cita con un datepicker, necesito saber cómo hacer para validar que la fecha que ingrese una persona no sea en tiempo pasado sino del día o fechas futuras ya que no puedo realizar citas en el pasado, esto se puede hacer en javascript?

```html
<TD align="right">Fecha</TD>
<td>
<input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" required>
</td>
```

Comment: Si estás usando datepicker: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/dAyzq/1/

Answer (score 7):

Para validar la fecha por el lado del servidor:

**[Ver Demo PHP](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ec6a97c1ecc6cb0d1ea9785edd45ba85f68e1bb)**

```
$hoy             = date("Y-m-d");
$fechaFormulario = "2016-11-09";

// Si la fecha es de apartir de hoy => true 
if ($hoy <= $fechaFormulario) {

    echo "Fecha a partir de hoy";
}
else {

    echo "Fecha pasado";
}
```

Validar por el lado cliente con `javascript`:

**[Ver Demo Javascript](http://jsbin.com/ziwoxe/edit?js,console)**

```
var hoy             = new Date();
var fechaFormulario = new Date('2016-11-10');

// Comparamos solo las fechas => no las horas!!
hoy.setHours(0,0,0,0);  // Lo iniciamos a 00:00 horas

if (hoy <= fechaFormulario) {

  console.log("Fecha a partir de hoy");
}
else {
  console.log("Fecha pasado");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Realmente hay muchas maneras, pero para tu problema en cuestión lo que YO haría sería para empezar, en el datepicker no dejar seleccionar días anteriores a hoy.

```
 var today = new Date();
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    ... <OTRAS OPCIONES>
    minDate: today 
    ... <OTRAS OPCIONES>
 });
```

Así entonces de primeras ya evitas que el usuario elija una fecha errónea (lo cual está genial en términos de usabilidad) y entonces, una vez tienes la fecha, IGUALMENTE la validaría para comprobar que no se ha trampeado.

Y cojiendo el código del compañero:

```
var hoy             = new Date();
var fechaFormulario = new Date('2016-11-10');

// Comparamos solo las fechas => no las horas!!
hoy.setHours(0,0,0,0);
fechaFormulario.setHours(0,0,0,0); // Lo iniciamos a 00:00 horas

if (hoy <= fechaFormulario) {

  console.log("Fecha a partir de hoy");
}
else {
  console.log("Fecha pasado");
}
```

Validamos la fecha y lo enviamos.

PD: Aún así en el lado del servidor (ya sea php o lo que tengas) validaria la fecha igualmente, ya que pueden modificar el envío y llegarte los datos incorrectos. 
PD2: Nunca te fies de lo que te envíe JavaScript, siempre valida en el servidor ;D

Answer (score 0):

Yo la validación la haría del lado del servidor. En el cliente la validación se salta de la forma más tonta que te puedas imaginar: solo hay que cambiar la fecha del sistema.

**Ejemplo**

En la consola escribes:

```
var hoy = new Date();
console.log( hoy );
```

Resultado: `Sun Jul 09 2017 10:48:15 GMT+0200 (Hora de verano romance)`

Ahora cambio la fecha al día uno de éste mes y vuelvo a escribir nuevamente en la consola:

```
var hoy = new Date();
console.log( hoy );
```

Resultado: `Sat Jul 01 2017 10:44:53 GMT+0200 (Hora de verano romance)`

Poco fiable.